# ggplot2 box_plot add number of observations

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this problem that should be trivial but none of the examples I have seen so far has been helpful. I have this melted dataframe in R and I want to do a box_plot with geom_points. So far the code works.

```
 head(df3)
  microRNAs        variable     value
1 geneA      LC1_average_TPM   520075.23
2 geneB      LC1_average_TPM   315802.96
3 geneC      LC1_average_TPM   13356.56
4 geneD      LC1_average_TPM   13348.82
5 geneE      LC1_average_TPM   13331.13
6 geneF      LC1_average_TPM   13309.27

ggplot(df3, aes(x=variable, y=log(value), fill=variable)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = variable))+
    geom_point(shape = 21, alpha = 0.9, position=position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 3, jitter.height = 0)) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +   scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,15), breaks=seq(0,15,1)) + theme(axis.text.x=element_blank()) + ylab("log2(Expression TPM)") +  xlab ("Libraries")
```

[image]

My problems is that I want to add observations to that plot. The observations are determined by how many datapoint each df3$variable got.

Comment: Try adding an extra column to your dataset like `df3 %>% group_by(variable) %>% mutate(group_n = length(variable)`. Then you can combine this with `geom_text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use mutate, as my comment suggested, it's doable but you'll get multiple n values repeated, you need to use `summarsie` and create a separate table. You will add this in the `geom_text()` call using the `data` argument. I named your `data.frame` "df" but adjust for `df3` in your case.

```
counts_df <- 
df %>%   
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  summarise(group_n = length(variable)) 
  
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=variable, y=log(value), fill=variable)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = variable))+
# this is what you want to add < ----  
  geom_text(
    data = counts_df,
    aes(variable, y=10,
                label=group_n))+
  geom_point(shape = 21, alpha = 0.9, position=position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 3, jitter.height = 0)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,15), breaks=seq(0,15,1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank()) +
  ylab("log2(Expression TPM)") +
  xlab ("Libraries")
```

which produces this horrible plot, adjust the aesthetics and the position for the `n` using the `y` argument.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!